# Get links in list from string

Tags: python, regex

I need some help with regexp in Python. I have string such as:

```
17:25:31;http://example1.com/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=189;example1.com;127.0.0.1 2013-10-19
17:22:32;http://example2.com;example2.com;127.0.0.1 2013-10-19 
20:18:28;http://example3.com/threads/example-text-in-url.27304/;example3.com;127.0.0.1 2013-10-19
```

How can I get this list?

```
['http://example1.com/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=189', 'http://example2.com', 'http://example3.com/threads/example-text-in-url.27304/']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to give a Regex solution since that is what you asked for.  Basically, all you need to do is capture text between `http://` and `;`.  Below is a demonstration:

```
from re import findall

mystr = """
17:25:31;http://example1.com/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=189;example1.com;127.0.0.1 2013-10-19
17:22:32;http://example2.com;example2.com;127.0.0.1 2013-10-19 
20:18:28;http://example3.com/threads/example-text-in-url.27304/;example3.com;127.0.0.1  2013-10-19
"""

print findall("(http://.+?);", mystr)
```

Output:

```
['http://example1.com/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=189', 'http://example2.com', 'http://example3.com/threads/example-text-in-url.27304/']
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need regex here, use a `csv` parser.

Assuming your data is in a file called `data.csv`:

```
import csv
reader = csv.reader(open("data.csv"), delimiter=";")
referers = [line[1] for line in reader]
```

Answer (score 1):

just try [this](http://regex101.com/r/qQ9eB1). maybe it fit your needs :)

Regex

```
/^(.*;)/gm
```

String

```
17:25:31;http://example1.com/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=189;example1.com;127.0.0.1 2013-10-19
17:22:32;http://example2.com;example2.com;127.0.0.1 2013-10-19 
20:18:28;http://example3.com/threads/example-text-in-url.27304/;example3.com;127.0.0.1 2013-10-19
```

Matches

```
1.  [0-66]    `17:25:31;http://example1.com/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=189;example1.com;`
2.  [87-129]  `17:22:32;http://example2.com;example2.com;`
3.  [151-228] `20:18:28;http://example3.com/threads/example-text-in-url.27304/;example3.com
```

Comment: While a link to a tester is handy, it's a good idea to put your regex in there too.  Links expire, for example, and if the link breaks your answer won't be useful anymore.

Comment: The `{1}` is completely redundant.

Comment: yep.. sorry for this ;)